# express rate limit for login route

Tags: node.js, express, handler, rate-limiting, express-rate-limit

my aim is  10 tires before lockout for 10 minutes. and if the user tries again and has 5 more failed attempts the lock time increase to 20 minutes. after 20 minutes, if the same user has 3 failed attempts lockout is 1 hour and finally, After 1 hour if the same user gets it wrong again, it locks them out for 24 hours.

how could I do that? I am using `express-rate-limit` and passing it as middleware

```
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');

    const apiLimiter = rateLimit({
        windowMs: 10 * 60 * 1000,
        headers: true,
        max: 10,
    });
    
    module.exports = apiLimiter;
```

the first attempt working but to do the next attempt.

Comment: is there anyone to give some info?

Comment: Your question is 30 minutes old. No reason to get impatient.

Comment: You need custom implementation using some storage. Perhaps redis store and write down your middleware to handle your business logic.

Comment: Huh? You don't need redis for this. A simple `Map` between IP address and `{lastUnsuccessfulAttempt: Date; countUnsuccessfulAttempts: Number}` is enough to figure out when any IP is allowed to try again.

Comment: @Tomalak  could you share the code, I am completely a beginner in this.

Comment: @freelanceingmindset I'm not going to write it all down, but the idea is: When your app starts, create a map (`knownIPs = new Map();`) and every time someone uses your `/login` route and fails, check if they are already in the list (`knownIPs.has(clientIP)`) - if not, add them to the map (`knownIPs.set(clientIP, {lastUnsuccessfulAttempt: new Date(); countUnsuccessfulAttempts: 1})`). If they are already known, retrieve their stats (`knownIPs.get(clientIP)`), increase the counter and do the math. If they have hit a limit, send `429 Too Many Requests`. Delete their entry when the login succeded.

Comment: (That also means you don't really need `express-rate-limit`.)

Comment: @Tomalak you are amazing. I got enough idea. let me Implement.  again thanks for your time.

Comment: I hardly did anything. :) If you end up with code that works, post it as an answer below and ping me, I'll have a look and comment/upvote.

Comment: @freelanceingmindset You can use [rate-limiter-flexible](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rate-limiter-flexible). I would create 4 different limiters with options you need. [Here is simple example](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Overall-example#minimal-protection-against-password-brute-force).

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by creating multiple instances of express-rate-limit and applying them all to each request:

```js
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');

app.post('/login', 

    // 10 tires in 10 minutes
    rateLimit({
        windowMs: 10 * 60 * 1000,
        headers: false,
        max: 10,
    }),

    // 5 more tries in 20 minutes
    rateLimit({
        windowMs: 20 * 60 * 1000,
        headers: false,
        max: 10 + 5,
    }),

    // 3 more tries in 1 hour
    rateLimit({
        windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,
        headers: false,
        max: 10 + 5 + 3,
    }),

    // 1 more try in 24 hours
    rateLimit({
        windowMs: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        headers: false,
        max: 10 + 5 + 3 + 1,
    }),

    function(req, res) {
        // handle login attempt here, if it passed all the rate limiters
    }
);
```

Handling the headers correctly can be tricky in this scenario, so I opted to just disable them in my example.

Important: if you use any `store` besides the built-in default memory store, be sure to create a new instance for each limit and use a unique `prefix` for each store instance.

---

Disclosure: I am the author of express-rate-limit